# Stuck on White Screen - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run the ADB on my device, it shows a white blank screen and it stays like that. This issue started occuring after I updated the Android STudio.
If you know how to fix this, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you see any errors/message in the console ?

Comment: have you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

turn off instance run.

- Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select
  File Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android Studio
  Preferences from the menu bar.
- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
- Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes.